# Expected Behavior for SharePoint Online/OneDrive Collaboration

Tags: sharepoint, microsoft-office-365, onedrive-for-business

I am trying to better understand the different "modes of operation" that are enabled by using the OneDrive client with SharePoint Online. For the sake of simplicity let's assume that all documents stored in a SharePoint document library are Office Documents (Word, PowerPoint, Excel) that are capable of online real-time collaboration.

User A opens a Word Document "File.doc" by opening Microsoft Word, navigating to Open > Sites > Team > Team Folder > and navigating to the file.

User B has the "Team Folder" syncing via Files On-Demand in the OneDrive Client. User B opens "File.doc" directly from the macOS Finder or Windows Explorer.

Both users have internet connectivity. User A opened the file first. What is the expected behavior?

1. Should both be able to seamlessly collaborate in "real-time"? or;
2. Does User B's revisions attempt to sync back and "clobber" User A's version causing a conflict?

Answer (score 0):

They should sync just fine. The Office apps, the web apps and the sync client all support online collaboration, i.e. merging changes each time you save or autosave.

If your sync app and Office suite are up-to-date it should work out of the box.

There are [some settings](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/use-office-applications-to-sync-office-files-that-i-open-8a409b0c-ebe1-4bfa-a08e-998389a9d823) that can be changed to tweak the behaviour, but I've never had to change them.